# Can load data in file take ftp file location

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there is any way to run

```
LOAD DATA INFILE
```

command, when file exists in FTP location? For example something like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'USER%40WEBSITE.COM:PASSWORD@ftp.WEBSITE.COM/FILE.csv'; 
REPLACE INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Comment: do you want load all/some data of mysql in FTP?? or explain in detail .

Comment: i want to load a file from ftp location (only one)  like this LOAD DATA INFILE
'ftp://USER%40WEBSITE.COM:PASSWORD@ftp.WEBSITE.COM/FILE.csv' REPLACE INTO
TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1
LINES

Comment: what is use of "MySQL" you have tagged you title with "mysql and SQL"?

Comment: i cant understand your question... ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, MySQL file-related functions can only access files on the database server or the client, but not other machines (unless you've set up a network file system mount, to make the remote machine appear to be local).

Comment: Not really. You can use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to load a file from the client host.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated to include both possibilities. But the question was about accessing a third-party URL, which isn't really possible.